# Run scripts with BashSupport in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I'm using the plugin BashSupport, I create a Bash script file. Whenever I run the script I get:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\bash.exe C:/Users/MyUser/PycharmProjects/studY/test.sh
/bin/bash: C:/Users/MyUser/test.sh: File or catalog doesn't exist

Process finished with exit code 127
```

Comment: `C:/Users/*` isn't going to resolve to a single file.

Comment: * is for my user anonymity.

Comment: Use another value in its place for the purposes of this question. `*` is normally used as a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

I believe bash for Windows still uses unix style paths, so the correct path would be `/mnt/c/Users/MyUser/PycharmProjects/studY/test.sh`